# How to autofocus working copy in the dynamic history view in mks integrity?

Tags: version-control

At work I use MKS Integrity for version control (and PLM). I wonder whether there is a possibility to automatically focus something reasonable, like the working copy or the member revision, in the member / project history view (I have set it to 'dynamic'). At the moment it always opens up at some more or less random position when I select a new member. Then I have to scroll around to find my working copy - that's really annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get MKS to open the *graphical* history view at a certain position. However, I just discovered that there is a *list* history view, which feels much more convenient to me. You can change the `Intial View` under `File -> Edit Preferences -> Configuration Management -> Views -> Member History View` (and `... Project History View` respectively). In the list view, things are clearly sorted and one can find specific revisions (working/member revision are marked with symbols at the beginning of the line) a lot quicker.
**NB:** when changing the settings for the history views, all history views have to be closed, otherwise the changes are not applied